# Symfony DI Extensions - add custom DoctrineExtension

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

There is a DoctrineExtension in the

`Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension`

package. I cant find where it   is defined in the framework and how do I replace this class by my own. I want to change some behavior of this extension.

Comment: wtf do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

The file itself is located under:  vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/DependencyInjection

I think to change it you will probably have to extend DoctrineBundle with:

```
public function getContainerExtension()
{
    return new MyDoctrineExtension();
}
```

Have not tried it myself.  I expect there will be plenty of other issues with trying to change such a core file.  But maybe not.  Let us know if it works.  Might come in handy.